# Count of distinct values of a table using sql

Tags: aggregate, count, distinct

```
name  number
=============
lin |   8
lin |   8
lin |   8
rob |   8
rob |   8
rob |   8
lin |   8
lin |   41
lin |   41
rob |   41
```

and I want the result like

```
name  |   Count of 8 |   count of 41
====================================
lin   |      4       |        2
rob   |      3       |       1
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Although not relevant for such  a basic question, you should always add the tag for your DBMS (`postgresql`, `oracle`, ...)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's not so basic (assuming I understand correctly they need some form of pivot, besides the aggregation.)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Even basic questions can get better answers if we know the exact DBMS. Each DBMS has unique features which can be used to solve even basic problems.

Comment: @Colin'tHart: that's why I said the question _should_ be tagged with the appropriate DBMS.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes: I'm taking issue with the first part of your sentence :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is know as conditional counting and can be achieved using a `case` expression:

```
select name, 
       count(case when number = 8 then 1 end) as count_of_8,
       count(case when number = 41 then 1 end) as count_of_41
from the_table
group by name
order by name;
```

Aggregate functions (like `count()`) ignore `NULL` values. The `case` expression inside the `count()` returns null for those values that we don't want to count, hence only the number of rows containing that value are counted. `case when x then y end` is equivalent to `case when x then y else null end`

Answer (score 2):

If using PostgreSQL 9.4+, the use of the new aggregate `filter` clause is the most efficient way to do this:

```
select
  name,
  count(*) filter (where number = 8) as count_of_8,
  count(*) filter (where number = 41) as count_of_41
from <table>
group by name;
```